# Simple things about jelastic & jetty

Tags: java, server, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I create maven project with dependencies. Than write simple jetty server which return html page on request. Simple "Hello World" application. Now i want relocate it on jelastic cloud, but can't understand how.

When creating cloud on jelastic you can add jetty server, but i need run my own. Maybe i need connect my servlets or another things. Or maybe i can run server.jar file which assembled by maven.

My google traveling failed. I even not imagine what i must search. Pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can't up your own servers on the native containers. Moreover, such containers don't provide the root access for a customer.

If you want to run your own server you can use either [VPS](https://docs.jelastic.com/vps) or [Docker](https://docs.jelastic.com/dockers-overview) solution in Jelastic Cloud.

Comment: if i choose VPS it will be able to use mysql in future?

Comment: Yes, you can install the MySQL database in the same way like on your local PC.